# Stone-Weierstrass theorem: coefficients of approximating sequence bounded?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{A}$ be a subalgebra of $C(X;\mathbb{R})$.

The Stone-Weierstrass theorem asserts that if $\mathcal{A}$ contains the constants and separates the points of $X$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $(C(X;\mathbb{R}), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$.

Suppose now that $\mathcal{A}$ is countably spanned, that is: $\mathcal{A}=\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\xi_\alpha\mid \alpha\in I)$ for $(\xi_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}=:\xi$ some countable linearly independent family in $C(X;\mathbb{R})$. (So in particular, $\xi$ is such that $\xi_\alpha\cdot\xi_{\tilde{\alpha}}\in\mathrm{span}(\xi)$ for any $\alpha, \tilde{\alpha}\in I$).

As a vector space, this $\mathcal{A}$ can be normed via $\|\sum_{\alpha\in J} c_\alpha\xi_\alpha\|:= (\sum_{\alpha\in J} c_\alpha^2)^{1/2}$ (any finite $J\subseteq I$).

Assuming that $\xi$ contains a constant and separates points, we for each $f\in C(X;\mathbb{R})$ can find a sequence $(p_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that

$$\tag{1}\|f - p_k\|_\infty \,\leq \, \tfrac{1}{k} \quad \text{for each } \ k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

My **question**: Do we have any reason to believe that the associated sequence of [coefficient-]norms $(\|p_k\|)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded? If not, are there some extra conditions under which boundedness would hold?

(Extra conditions might be that $\xi$ is square-summable, i.e. $\|\xi(x)\|_{L^2}:=\sum_{\alpha\in I}\xi_\alpha(x)^2 < \infty$ for each $x\in X$, etc.)

Comment: It's granted that $\xi$ separates points.

Comment: @WlodAA Yes, this is one of the assumptions prior to eq. (1).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is negative. Suppose we approximate a continuous function on $[-1,1]$ with ordinary
polynomialss $P_n$. If the coefficients are bounded, say
$|a_{n,k}|\leq C$, then
$$|P_n(z)|\leq C(1-|z|)^{-1},\quad |z|<1$$
Therefore $\{ P_n\}$ is a normal family in the unit disk,
and thus there is a subsequence which converges to an analytic function uniformly on compact subsets of $|z|<1$.
So if the function which we approximate is not analytic, the coefficients
cannot be bounded.

This also suggests a sufficient condition for boundedness of coefficients: if the function $f$ that you approximate is analytic in a disk $|z|<1+\epsilon,$ with some $\epsilon>0$, then its Taylor coefficients are bounded by Cauchy inequality, and initial segments of the Taylor series give a
uniform approximation on $[-1,1]$ by polynomials
with bounded coefficients.